# How to have different UserTokenProvider lifespans for different uses. Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

In the IdentityConfig we can set the UserTokenProvider to have an expiration lifespan that is used for every token that is generated. IdentityConfig is run at startup..

```
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")) 
                { TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) };
```

But is it possible when generating a new token in your controller:

```
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

That you can use a different lifespan for that user/token?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is quite old but since it comes up in searches: it's not currently possible. There's a workitem for it on codeplex (https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2228)

Answer (score 1):

I created some extension methods:

```
public static class UserManagerExtensions
{
    public static Task<string> GenerateAdjustableUserTokenAsync<TUser,TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TUser user, string purpose = null) 
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey> 
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        if (manager == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        var dataProtector = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyTokenizedApp").Create(purpose);
        var tokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>(dataProtector);
        return tokenProvider.GenerateAsync(purpose, manager, user);
    }

    public static string GenerateAdjustableUserToken<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TUser user, string purpose)
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        return GenerateAdjustableUserTokenAsync(manager, user, purpose).Result;
    }

    public static Task<bool> VerifyAdjustableUserTokenAsync<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, string token, TUser user, string purpose = null, TimeSpan? timeSpan = null)
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        if (manager == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        if (token == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("token");

        var dataProtector = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyTokenizedApp").Create(purpose);
        var tokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>(dataProtector)
        {
            TokenLifespan = timeSpan ?? TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
        };
        return tokenProvider.ValidateAsync(purpose, token, manager, user);
    }

    public static bool VerifyAdjustableUserToken<TUser, TKey>(this UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, string token, TUser user, string purpose = null, TimeSpan? timeSpan = null)
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        return VerifyAdjustableUserTokenAsync(manager, token, user, purpose, timeSpan).Result;
    }
}
```